# Tabs are not navigating properly at the time of template field creation – Keyword Accessibility

Tags: content-editor

Create any template and add Any field under the section and navigate the field name, Type , Source , Unversioned , shared  properties by keyword tabs, it gets stuck in the unversioned field(checkbox), Cannot navigate further by keyword Tabs.

I am using Sitecore 8.2 update 3

Any solution for the same?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just blogged about it recently. Here is the whole blog post: [Sitecore Template Manager - fix for the Tab key](https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-template-manager-fix-for-the-tab-key).

And the solution in shortcut:

Open the `\sitecore\shell\Controls\Sitecore.js` file and replace the following:

```
if (evt.keyCode == 8 && (srcElement.className && srcElement.className.toLowerCase().indexOf("checkbox") >= 0) ||
  (srcElement.type && srcElement.type.toLowerCase() == "checkbox")) {
  scForm.browser.clearEvent(evt, false, false, 8);
}
```

with

```
if (evt.keyCode == 8 && ((srcElement.className && srcElement.className.toLowerCase().indexOf("checkbox") >= 0) ||
  (srcElement.type && srcElement.type.toLowerCase() == "checkbox"))) {
  scForm.browser.clearEvent(evt, false, false, 8);
}
```

Comment: Hi Marek, Its still not working, I am using Sitecore 8.2 update 3..

Comment: Did you remember to clear all browser caches?   I just tried it on 8.2u4 and it works.

Comment: Hi Mark Thanks, Working fine for me, Caching Issue..